# Magento2 - How to remove the side navigation bar only in my account page?

Tags: magento2, design, page-layouts

I need to remove the side bar **only** in `My Account` page.

I had removed the side bar in `Magento_Customer > Layout > customer_account.xml` but it removes from all the pages like (my address page,view orders page).

Code:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Customer My Account (All Pages)" design_abstraction="custom">
<head>
    <title>My Accounts</title>
</head>
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="sidebar.main.account_nav" remove="true"/>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to create this file

> customer_account_index.xml

and add below line in that XML and clear Magento cache and check

```
<referenceBlock name="sidebar.main.account_nav" remove="true"/>
```

**UPDATE :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

</page>
```

Here you can see `layout="1column"` in above content (You can use `2columns-left`, `2columns-right`, or your custom layout name here). It will change layout of your customer account page.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Can i change page to single column page @kishan savaliya

Comment: Yes, Please check my updated answer @Sabareesh

Comment: Yes bro it is working thanks brother :-)

Comment: You're welcome ;-)